# Show that there exists a continuous function $q$ such that $f(x) = q(x)(x-x_1)$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, proof-writing, solution-verification

Let $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a polynomial function of degree $n \geq 1$. Let $x_1$ be a root of $f$ with $x_1 \in \mathbb{R}$. Show that there exists a unique function $q : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x) = q(x)(x - x_1)$. Show that $q$ is a polynomial function with degree $n-1$.

I was thinking about using the intermediate value theorem. Because $f$ is a polynomial function, it is a continuous function on $\mathbb{R}$, so it is also continuous on interval $[x_1, x]$ for every $x > x_1$ (and continuous on $[x, x_1]$ for every $x < x_1$). Polynomials are also differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$, so it is differentiable on $(x_1 , x)$. Applying the intermediate theorem, there exists a $c \in [x_1, x]$ such that

$$\frac{f(x) - f(x_1)}{x-x_1} = f'(c).$$
Since $f(x_1) = 0$ we find 
$$f'(c) = \frac{f(x)}{x-x_1}.$$

If we apply it for the interval $[x,x_1]$ we find that there exists a $c_1 \in [x,x_1]$ such that
$$\frac{- f(x_1)}{x_1-x} = f'(c_1).$$

I am just not sure how exactly I have to define $q(x)$ and what else I need to write to finish the proof.

Comment: Why not use polynomial division with remainder (which is $0$)?

Comment: I think you have forgotten a limit as $x$ tends to $x_1$

Comment: Instead of saying "Intermediate Value Theorem", I guess you meant with the "Mean Value Theorem".

Answer (score 2):

We know we can write
$$f(x)=q(x)(x-x_1)+r(x)$$
via normal polynomial division with $\deg r<\deg x-x_1=1$ (there are plenty of proofs for this fact online). But then plugging in $x_1$ gives us
$$f(x_1)=q(x_1)(x_1-x_1)+r(x_1)\quad \implies \quad 0=r(x_1)$$
since $x_1$ is a root of $f$. However, $r$ is a constant since its degree is less than $1$, so $r(x_1)=0$, giving us
$$f(x)=q(x)(x-x_1)$$
Now, we easily see that since degrees of polynomials add through multiplication, the degree of $q(x)$ must be $n-1$ since $f$ has degree $n$ and $x-x_1$ has degree $1$.

Uniqueness comes from the division algorithm.

Comment: Here, you made a mistake. One part of your proof, you needed to write "$r(x) = 0$, for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$", otherwise, only $r(x)$ will be $0$ only at $x_1$.